# Check how many rows add up to a number (check inventory coverage days ) in Pandas or PySpark for big data

Tags: python, pandas, loops, pyspark, count

I'm trying to find the number of days the available inventory will last. Data (simplified) is in the form of this table.

| Date | Closing Stock | Demand | Substitute |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1-Jan | 7 | 3 | 11 |
| 2-Jan | 4 | 3 | 22 |
| 3-Jan | 3 | 1 | 33 |
| 4-Jan | 3 | 0 | 44 |
| 5-Jan | 3 | 0 | 55 |
| 6-Jan | 5 | 7 | 66 |
| 7-Jan | 5 | 1 | 77 |
| 8-Jan | 10 | 2 | 88 |
| 9-Jan | 0 | 2 | 99 |
| 10-Jan | 10 | 2 | 111 |
| 11-Jan | 5 | 2 | 222 |

Coverage is calculated as the number of days in future, the closing stock of the current day can fulfill.

Closing stock of 1-Jan = 7, and it can be used to fulfill demand of 2-Jan (Demand=3), 3-Jan (=1), 4-Jan (=0), 5-Jan (=0) and a portion of 6-Jan (only 3 units can be fulfilled, since 4 units (3+1+0+0) have already been used up).

So, the coverage is calculated as 1+1+1+1+3/7 = 4.43 days

When Closing Stock > sum of all future demands (happens at 10-Jan)
or for the last row in data (11-Jan),
then Coverage should return a value from Substitute Column.

Coverage needs to be calculated for a large dataset with ~1 Million rows in Databricks. The original data contains many different materials at multiple locations.

| Date | Closing Stock | Demand | Substitute | Coverage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1-Jan | 7 | 3 | 11 | 4.43 |
| 2-Jan | 4 | 3 | 22 | 3.43 |
| 3-Jan | 3 | 1 | 33 | 2.43 |
| 4-Jan | 3 | 0 | 44 | 1.43 |
| 5-Jan | 3 | 0 | 55 | 0.43 |
| 6-Jan | 5 | 7 | 66 | 3 |
| 7-Jan | 5 | 1 | 77 | 4 |
| 8-Jan | 10 | 2 | 88 | 2.50 |
| 9-Jan | 0 | 2 | 99 | 0 |
| 10-Jan | 10 | 2 | 111 | 111 |
| 11-Jan | 5 | 2 | 222 | 222 |

I'm not able to find a straightforward approach to use to calculate Coverage. Any help on this is greatly appreciated. Thanks!